# Move another user to a room with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using Socket.io with Node.js and I would like to pair users up and send them to a new room.

When a user connects, within `io.on('connection')` I determine their compatibility with a user waiting to be paired in an array.

If the user who has joined is compatible with a waiting user, I want to move them both to a new room.

This is my current approach. Note: `[1029387,1983934,9243802]` is an array of user IDs.

```
var pendingPlayers = {
    "spelling": {
        "level1":[1029387,1983934,9243802],
        "level2":[]
     }
}


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // check compatibility
    // move current player and other queued player to new room
});
```

The only idea I have is to `socket.emit('room', 'new room name');` from server to client, for the queued player to send this ID back to the server and then use:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('room', function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
    });
});
```

However, sending the room name to the client, to then send it back to the server seems awfully far-fetched. I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Your suggestions are gratefully received.

Comment: Why send room to the client from the server? Just move the client right into that room from the server.  No need to ask the client to help you do that.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00, but I need to move another user to another room (not the user in question). Hope this makes sense?

Comment: There's no reason you can't just do that from the server at the moment you want to - for any user that is currently connected to your server.  What information are you using to identify your users?

Comment: I intend to use a unique user ID to identify users, although I haven't got that far yet.

Comment: Well, there doesn't appear to be enough information for us to understand how, at the moment you know which two users you want to put in the same room, how you would get the socket for both of those users.  We'd have to see the code around where this happens to know what info is available or whether we need to recommend keeping a new type of data structure in order to be able to identify sockets.  If you use the socket.id as the identifier, then socket.io will let you look up the socket directly from that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I agree I should've better explained the context. There are two keys in the object - "level1" and "level2". Users are paired in the same level with another player. If there are no players already in the pendingPlayers object for the respective level, the user who is joining a game is added to the pendingPlayers object. Then, the next player who requests to join the respective level will be paired with the player ID that is .push()'ed from the array corresponding that level.

Comment: If I was to identify players with their socket ID to make things simpler... If I stored that in the array instead, how could I make that socket ID join the room? `socket.join('room');` would make the *current* user join the room, but this question relates to moving another user. I can put the whole code on Pastebin if still unclear. I appreciate the help! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment

> If there are no players already in the pendingPlayers object for the
>   respective level, the user who is joining a game is added to the
>   pendingPlayers object.

Rather than moving to object, make a new room with only this player for that level. Now when new player come as per your comment

> Then, the next player who requests to join the respective level will
>   be paired with the player ID that is .push()'ed from the array
>   corresponding that level.

make that next player join the above room.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need some logic like in the battleship game. It is used temporary 'waiting room'. I found it here:
https://github.com/inf123/NodeBattleship/blob/master/server.js

```js
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  //firstly add player to room until opponent aren't come
  socket.join('waiting room');

  joinWaitingPlayers();
});

function joinWaitingPlayers () {
  var clients = [];
  for (var id in io.sockets.adapter.rooms['waiting room']) {
    clients.push(io.sockets.adapter.nsp.connected[id]);
  }

  if (clients.length >= 2) {
    //if we have a couple, then start the game
    var game = new Game();

    // live "waiting room"
    clients[0].leave('waiting room');
    clients[1].leave('waiting room');
    // and then join both to another room
    clients[0].join('game' + game.id);
    clients[1].join('game' + game.id);

  }
}
```